# Why jupyter is not able to download as pdf a markdown cell using LaTex \mathscr?

Tags: latex, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, xelatex, nbconvert

Just created a markdown cell in Jupyter using some equations, and some of them using \mathscr to have like "math" fonts. When I run the kernel containing the equations everything is ok, however when I click the option to Download as PDF via LaTex, I'm getting the error below:

! Undefined control sequence.
l.300 [\mathscr
                {L}({\bf{y}}|\beta, \sigma^2, {\bf{X}})  = (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-...

? 
! Emergency stop.
l.300 [\mathscr
                {L}({\bf{y}}|\beta, \sigma^2, {\bf{X}})  = (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-...

If I remove the \mathscr part everything can be exported with no issues (excepting some convertion problems for special characters), however, I wanted to know ho to solve it. I've been reading and it looks like the nbconvert configuration file can be modified to solve this, but I couldn't find the mentioned file and the exact way to modify it

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with absent `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` directive in an intermediate `.tex`-file. 
So you have a several ways to overcome it.
If you face with this problem occasianaly you could the following:

- download the `.tex`-file instead `pdf`;
- manually insert to `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` to it.
  before the first `\usepackage` for example;
- run something like
  `xelatex file.tex` to finally convert to pdf.

If you will do it often, you could try to edit appropriate jinja-template.

- At first, find the place where `nbconvert` was installed. For example with pip: `pip show nbconvert`. Imagine the path is `/home/i/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`
- Then the template would be at `/home/i/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/templates/latex/base.tplx`.
- And again: just add `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` right after `((* block packages *))`.

Voila -- the problem should gone.

At the end you have the third option -- you can create your own template from scratch and use it with `nbconvert`. I don't think it's very convenient way to solve your problem. You could read more in the documentation: http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html